# How to extract list of users from the text file created from getfacl from linux using bash scripts or awk or grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep, acl

I extracted the ACL list from the directories/files using getfacl and save it to a file (ie.ACL.txt) and we need to extract only for a certain userid only (ie. user1) from the ACLs:

```
# file: folder1
# owner: user1
# group: usergroup1
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:usergroup1:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:usergroup1:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: folder1/subfolder1
# owner: user2
# group: usergroup2
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:usergroup2:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:usergroup2:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: folder1/subfolder2
# owner: user3
# group: usergroup3
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:usergroup2:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:usergroup2:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: folder2/subfolder2
# owner: user1
# group: usergroup1
user::rw-
group::r-x
group:usergroup1:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

I need a bash script to extract for a certain user/group and write it to a new file like the one below (search for user1group1):

```
# file: folder1
# owner: user1
# group: usergroup1
group:usergroup1:rwx
default:group:usergroup1:rwx

# file: folder2/subfolder2
# owner: user1
# group: usergroup1
group:usergroup1:rwx
```

Anybody can help?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly do post your efforts in form of code in our question. Also logic of getting your sample expected output is not clear, please explain that too in your question and let us know then.

Comment: the logic for the expected output is to read the acl text file (ACL.txt) and find if the userid have access to any file/folder.. if found then write it to a new text file with the printing the first 3 lines (# file, # owner, #group) and the line with userid.. the ACL.txt is delimited with a blank space as another record as shown in the example..

Comment: Sorry but its still not clear, you said you want to look for group and user but your expected output has only `group:usergroup1`, kindly post small and clear samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: to make it simple..i would like to search a string (ie.userid) then print the first 3 comments of the record (which is the '# file', '# owner', '# group') and the line with the search string (which is the userid) and output it to a file.

Comment: Any time you post sample input or output or code that requires us to use a scrollbar to read it all that discourages many people from trying to help you as it means you didn't put the effort into coming up with a [mcve], emphasis on **Minimal**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to filter the lines. It takes two (optional) parameters U and G, which indicates the user and group that should be extracted:

```
awk -F: -vOFS=: -v U=user1 -v G=usergroup1 '
    # Copy empty/comment lines
!$0 || /#.*/ { print ; next }
$1 == "user" && $2 && $2 == U { print ; next }
$1 == "group" && $2 && $2 == G { print ; next }
$1 == "default" && $2 == "user" && $3 && $3 == U { print ; next }
$1 == "default" && $2 == "group" && $3 && $3 == G { print ; next }
' < acl.txt
```

Comment: You forgot the `-v` in front of `U=` and `G=`. Also if you don't put a space between `-v` and the variable name (e.g. `-vOFS=` instead of `-v OFS=`) then your script becomes unnecessarily gawk-only.